# bash ldap search - variable as filter

Tags: bash, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am arguing with something i expected to be simple....

I want to lookup a users manager from ldap, then get the managers email and sam name.

I expected to be able to get the cn for the manager from ldap like this:

```
manager=$(/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://company.ads -x -D admin@company.ads -w password -b ou=employees,dc=company,dc=ads sAMAccountName=employee1 | grep "manager:" | awk '{gsub("manager: ", "");print}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}; {print $1, $2 }' )
```

that gives me the cn like this:

```
CN=manager,\ Surname
```

Now when I run another query like this:

```
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://company.ads -x -D admin@company.ads -w password -b ou=employees,dc=company,dc=ads $manager
```

I get bad search filter (-7) echo the command copy, paste run it i get the record back....

Ive tried a number of variations on this, can anyone see what im missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's a space in `$manager`, you need to quote it to prevent it from being split into multiple arguments.

```
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://company.ads -x -D admin@company.ads -w password -b ou=employees,dc=company,dc=ads "$manager"
```

In general, it's best to always quote your variables, unless you specifically want it to be split into words.

You also need to remove the backslash `\` from the LDAP entry. Backslashes are for escaping literal spaces in scripts, they shouldn't be used in data, because they're not processed when expanding variables.

Comment: Ive added the quotes, but still get the same result, bad search filter, echo and past it again it works. it must be related to this, some bad escaping somewhere.

Comment: Does `$manager` really contain that backslash? Backslashes aren't processed when expanding variables, so that will be sent literally as the filter.

Comment: yes it is in the variable, it is returned from ad when i get the CN, so seems my issue is the \?

Comment: If you type `manager,\ Surname` interactively, the backslash escapes the space so it's a single argument. Escaping isn't necessary when the value is in a variable. I don't understand why the AD is returning it like that.

Comment: You could remove the backslash in the `awk` script. BTW, you don't need to use two `awk` scripts, you can do the `gsub()` in the same script as `print $1, $2`.

Comment: if i enter the query by hand with the \ it returns the record, with out it nothing.

Comment: Seems you were right! removing the \ then quoting it seems to solve it. Im sure i tried it before.... its been a long day! Thanks for the help